When setting parameters in ompython, can you propagate calculated parameters to subclasses?
I am modeling a system in open modelica.  I have a top level model with multiple instances of similar subclasses that have their parameters set differently depending on the instance.  Below is an example of the top level model settings.
model Example
  import SI = Modelica.Units.SI;

  parameter SI.Position COGLoc[3] = {1, 2, 1};
  parameter SI.Position offset1 = {0, 1, 0};
  parameter SI.Position offset1 = {0, -1, 0};

  Class1 Instance1(COGOffs = COGLoc .+ offset1);
  Class1 Instance1(COGOffs = offset1 .- COGLoc);

I want to very COGLoc and see the affect on the system.
I tried using the setParameters() method in omPython, but when I check the parameters using getParameters(), only the top level parameter has changed, and it has not recacluated the COGOffs for the two instances.  Is there a way to do this, or would I need to replicate all of the calculations in python so I can set the entire parameter structure?
